# environment_server doesn't subscribe to collision_map

Tags: ros, collision-map, arm-navigation, environment-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to generate a collision map from kinect's pointcloud and use this info to do a collision-free arm navigation. so i write a node to receive pointcloud from kinect and publish collison_map with the topic "collision_map_occ". i think i've done this correctly because i can see these collision map green boxes in rviz. but it seems that environment_server doesn't subscribe to the collision_map topic. i'm sure that the param use_collision_map is set to true. does anybody know why?

besides, according to this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Planning%20Scene/Understanding%20the%20Planning%20Scene%20architecture), "If the use_collision_map parameter for the environment_server is set to true there must be a supplier of the CollisionMap or the environment_server will not start", but after i stop the collision_map publisher, the environment_server can still start successfully.

btw, i'm using Fuerte on Ubuntu12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45467/environment_server-doesn%27t-subscribe-to-collision_map/) by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 741 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-10-11**:
Can you post your edit as an answer to your own question, and then accept it? That way it will show up as "answered" in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After digging into the src of environment_server, i find that to make environemnt_server subscribe to collision_map, one must set both use_monitor and use_collision_map to true. so i just leave this question here in the hope that it can help other people.

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0